# Text in divs won't line up

Tags: css, html, text, colors

I’m making a website that has a title with differently colored words and fonts. To do this, I’ve put each word in a different div id to change the text color. I’m not sure if there is a better way than this…

Anyway, the first half of the title (the colored part) is lower than the rest of the title. It shows up this way on Firefox and Chrome, but on Internet Explorer it looks just fine. I’m not sure why there is a difference, I’ve tried out different fonts, which sometimes lessens the problem, but never completely eliminates it. Of course, when I add padding to make it line up, it messes it up on Internet Explorer.

Here’s the link for the page: http://www.dinneronthespot.com/index2.html

Comment: I don't see the first half of the tile lowe than the rest on all browsers

Comment: Are you talking about the _Dinner
On The
Spot
Personal Meal Service is perfect for..._ line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is, use `span`

```
<span id="dotPerfect">
    <span id="color1">Dinner </span>
    <span id="color2">On The </span>
    <span id="color3">Spot </span>
</span >
<span id="dotPersonal">Personal Meal Service is perfect for...</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
#topText > h1 > div {
    display: inline;
}
```

add this code in the stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Use `span` instead of `div` for this kind of actions.

```
<h1>
    <span id="color1">Dinner </span><span id="color2">On The </span><span id="color3">Spot </span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I’ve put each word in a different div id to change the text color.
>   I’m not sure if there is a better way than this…

It's better to use `<span>`-Tags

DIV-Tags do also have a default property "display:block" from user agent style, that's the reason why you have to set "float:left" (which is really ugly in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="dotPerfect">
  <div id="color1">Dinner </div>
  <div id="color2">On The </div>
  <div id="color3">Spot </div>
  <div id="dotPersonal">Personal Meal Service is perfect for...</div>
</div>
```

Move the div with id **dotPersonal** to div with id **dotPerfect**.